# what wrong with this code?. Converting VBA to VB.Net

Tags: vba, vb.net

I would like to ask if someone can help me with this.
I have this code that Unload a CorelDRAW Macro project a get the new one from the network in order to became easier to update several machines.
VBA code:

```
Sub CDRMacroUpdate()
' Unloads the project from CorelDRAW
    GMSManager.Projects("Project1").Unload
    Dim nMacro As String
' The project have the same name, but it's a new file, here is in the C drive, but it's located in the network folder
    nMacro = "C:\Project1.gms"
' Loads the new file and copy to the User GMS folder
    GMSManager.Projects.Load nMacro, True, False
End Sub
```

Now I'm trying to convert this VB.Net but I'm getting a lot of errors and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

In a form with a Button I have this code:
I'm using SharpDevelop

```
Imports Corel.Interop.VGCore
Public Partial Class MainForm
    Public Sub New()
        ' The Me.InitializeComponent call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    
    Sub BtnUpdateMacroClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim GMSManager As Corel.Interop.VGCore.GMSManager
        GMSManager.Projects("Project1").Unload 
        Dim nMacro As String
        nMacro = "C:\Project1.gms"
        GMSManager.Projects.Load(nMacro, True, False)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong in the VB.Net code?

Thank very much for the help.

Comment: What are those errors, exactly?

Comment: "I'm getting a lot of errors" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.  Did you mean to set `GMSManager` to something?  It's declared but not assigned.

Comment: I’m sorry for not explaining better. 
I’m getting something like as Williams wrote, “ It's declared but not assigned”. 
I know that it’s not doing something but I can’t figure it out.

Comment: How is `BtnUpdateMacroClick` associated with any events? In VB.NET you would typically have `Handles BtnUpdateMacro.Click` after the `Sub` signature, ..or does `InitializeComponent` add the handler (meaning the handler was associated with the button from the designer)? It's very difficult to diagnose a problem, without knowing what the problem is. Imagine what your response would be for receiving a user email saying "I'm getting a lot of errors, any idea what I'm doing wrong" without much further details about what they're doing and what the error is.

Comment: Note that "variable is declared but not assigned" would be a warning, not an error. Getting a `NullReferenceException` upon invocation of `GMSManager.Projects` would be an error, and indeed it looks like `GMSManager` is declared but never assigned. How does the VBA code get a reference to the `GMSManager` object? If it's a global object, you probably need to pull it from an existing `Corel.Interop.Application` instance.

Comment: I'm using SharpDevelop that's why I don't have "Handles BtnUpdateMacro.Click"

Comment: How is `GMSManager` instantiated in the VBA code?

Comment: I just start using it. For example:
GMSManager.Projects("Project1").Unload
And it will Unload the Macro from CorelDRAW.